# WCF Multiple Services - same backing class, different service behavior

Tags: wcf, service

I have a single service, one backing binary, that I want to configure to have two different endpoints.  The problem is, I want a different serviceBehavior for each endpoint, to specify different security requirements.

E.G:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="behavior1" name="MyServiceClass">
  <endpoint address="endpoint1" bindingConfiguration="binding1" contract="IMyServiceContract"/>
</service>
<service behaviorConfiguration="behavior2" name="MyServiceClass">
  <endpoint address="endpoint2" bindingConfiguration="binding2" contract="IMyServiceContract"/>
</service>
```

Is such a WCF configuration valid, or attainable in another format?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do it from config only, but there exists a code and config solution based around the extensibility point exposed by the [IEndpointBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx) interface. This allows you to define [behaviors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731403(v=vs.110).aspx) at the endpoint level.

It's not particularly well documented as I don't think it's used very often. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms730137(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Endpoint behaviors, which implement IEndpointBehavior, are the primary
>   mechanism by which you modify the entire service or client run time
>   for a specific endpoint.
>
> There are two mechanisms for adding endpoint behaviors to a service.
>
> 1. Add the behavior to the Behaviors property.
> 2. Implement a custom BehaviorExtensionElement that extends
>      configuration.

Specific examples of the first option exist [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.behaviors(v=vs.100).aspx), and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/05/wcf-extensibility-iendpointbehavior.aspx), but I can't find anything about the second.